# LOAD DATA INFILE not working on my server

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I have a csv with 400k records that I am trying to import into an existing database table but it is not working. I get no errors it simply says MYSQL returned an empty result.

Here is the query I am executing.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\projects\\csvTest\\newDataList.csv'
INTO TABLE peeps
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (first, last,address,city,state,zip,imb,email,startDate,endDate,jobName)
SET id = NULL
```

Funny thing is I run this exact code on my local host machine and it works, but if I run it on my server machine it does not work.

Comment: Is the CSV file actually present on your server machine?  Is your server even a Windows machine or is it Linux?

Comment: It is present in the server machine. The server is Windows 7 PRO with a LAMP stack.

Comment: How can it have a LAMP stack if it be running Windows?  Don't you mean an AMP stack?

Comment: Does MySQL have permissions on the server to read the file?

Comment: How could I check that?

Comment: Right click the file and check properties.  Give the CSV file universal rights.

Comment: In case it is an issue with the path being interpreted as relative, try putting the same .csv file into the database's data folder (whatever database to which this peeps table belongs) and change your infile location to just 'newDataList.csv' and see if it loads.

Comment: Here is what I got when I put the file into the data folder Error
SQL query:


LOAD DATA INFILE 'newData.csv' INTO TABLE cobs FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (first, last,address,city,state,zip,imb,email,start_date,end_date,job_name) SET id = NULL
MySQL said: Documentation

#29 - File 'C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\Mysql\data\dealer_data\newData.csv' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Comment: No.  Brian's suggestion was that you _also_ change the filename to just `newData.csv`.  Get rid of that path and try again.

Comment: OK I  just put the file into the databases data folder, but still returned an empty result set.

Comment: Would it be a issue with the file size? Its 33,000KB

Comment: Try changing '\n' to  '\r\n' . That is the default line terminator for flat files produced in Windows apps. Also check all column data types and lengths. Maybe create a simple 1 column table and a 1 column / 1 row csv in the same database, w/ the csv in the same data folder, just to rule out those sort of issues. At which point you know it is most likely permissions related. In what way are you running this statement? mysql.exe over  the command line or a data access tool?

Comment: That also did not work.  Its weird it gives me no error, but it also does not put the data into the database

Comment: When you say "Funny thing is I run this exact code on my local host machine and it works, but if I run it on my server machine it does not work." it almost suggests that you might really be running this query on a machine other than the server. Because in order for this to work running a the remote machine you would have had to add the word "local". The fact you got it to run on machine X implies that machine X must really be the one running the server.

Comment: I have a PC with xampp on it, its a small pc I use to write code, when I run this query on my PC it works and puts the csv data into my database. I also have a server which has the same database as my pc. When I run the query on my server it does not put the csv data into the database.

Comment: Try setting max_allowed_packet in my.ini on the server w/ the problem to something above 33 megabytes, like 50 megabytes. Then restart the mysql server and try again.

Comment: Execute "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';". The setting is returned in bytes. The setting is returned in bytes. Refer MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) . You must increase this value if you are using large BLOB columns or long strings. It should be as big as the largest BLOB you want to use. The protocol limit for max_allowed_packet is 1GB". It is simply the length of the INSERT query string that cannot exceed max_allowed_packet. If it does, the MySQL server will disconnect the client.

Answer (score 0):

Start and End are reserved words so you either need to enclose the column names in backticks, or better yet re-name those columns

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that, I changed the names to how they actually are on the database.